# Unable to Delete Printer w/ Apostrophe (') Using PRNMNGR

Tags: batch-file, command-line, vbscript, special-characters, apostrophe

I have a printer named "`Teacher's Lounge Printer`" *(note the apostrophe)*.

When executing the following command at a standard Windows 7 Command Prompt, "`Error 0x8004103A Invalid object path`" occurs.

```
cscript "%WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "Teacher's Lounge Printer"
```

If I rename the printer to "`Teachers Lounge Printer`" *(without the apostrophe)*, the command without the apostrophe will execute successfully.

```
cscript "%WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs" -d -p "Teachers Lounge Printer"
```

I feel like I've tried every combination of double-quotes, single-quotes, and I've even attempted escape characters.

Eventually, this will make it into a batch script I'm writing, but I need to get the individual command working properly, first.

I know I'm doing something wrong, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `\'`?

Comment: Yes.
`Unable to delete printer Teacher\'s Lounge Printer Error 0x8004103A Invalid object path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's prnmngr.vbs script uses WMI to provide the underlying functionality.

WMI accepts quoted strings using either single `'` quotes, or double `"` quotes. Unfortunately the developer of prnmngr.vbs chose to use single quotes in two places, which causes problems when the printer name contains single quotes (apostrophe).

I haven't figured out a way to escape the `'` in a prnmnger.vbs parameter in a way that WMI will accept. But I have figured out how to hack (debug) the Microsoft prnmngr.vbs code to eliminate the problem.

On my machine, there are two identical offending lines at line numbers 462 and 818.

```
        set oPrinter = oService.Get("Win32_Printer.DeviceID='" & strPrinter & "'")
```

The bug can be fixed by switching to using double quotes in the WMI query string. Since the double quote literals are within a VBS quoted string, the quotes must be escaped as `""`.

```
        set oPrinter = oService.Get("Win32_Printer.DeviceID=""" & strPrinter & """")
```

Rather than modifying the original Microsoft file, you may want to copy the file into a different folder, and make the changes there, and run that hacked version instead of the Microsoft original.

Comment: I noticed that `prnmngr.vbs` deletes printers with apostrophes `'` properly, when using the `-x` parameter, which deletes all printers.  I'll have a look at the VBS file, but I'm curious as to how the code differs.

Comment: @wmbell - Deleting a specific printer requires a WMI query with a where clause that specifies the name of the printer as a quoted value. The query returns the specified printer object. Deleting all printers simply iterates all available printers without requiring a where clause, so no quoted value.

Comment: Looks like the `-x` parameter uses a FOR EACH loop on each `Win32_Printer` instance, instead of querying the printers by name.  This would explain why the `-x` parameter works and the `-d -p` parameters don't.

Comment: On a side note... It also appears that this exact issue exists within several of the other built-in printing VBS files.

Comment: @dbenham I tried your hack.  Still get the same error.  I have a remote store that thought they were being cute by renaming their printer "DON'T USE".  Can't delete it.